# Why does input[type='tel'] allow non-numerical characters to be entered?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

Why does the input field allow alphabetic characters and not restrict the input to only numbers?

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone_number" placeholder="555-555-5555" pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}">
```

Comment: type=tel is only used to bring up the numpad on supported devices and browsers. It does not perform any validation / restriction on user input

Comment: Maybe for country code (+44) and area code (444) syntax.

Comment: [It's all explained in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel).

Answer (score 2):

It does not restrict the types of characters that can be input, but browsers will prevent submission if the input value does not match your pattern.

If you do not want to allow certain character inputs, you can use JavaScript to remove those characters: `onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');"`.

```css
input:invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone_number" placeholder="555-555-5555" pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because many country use char in the phone numbers like ’+-()’ space etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Andy's link to the documentation had the answer I was looking for.

> the input value is not automatically validated to a particular format before the form can be submitted, because formats for telephone numbers vary so much around the world